# How to replace each specific value in MatchCollection with a specific value C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using Regex to find all  tag in HTML, I would like to replace each one of them with a new  tag from a list the I have.

tried:

```
while (regx.IsMatch(html) && count < urls.Count)
{
    newhtml = regx.Replace(newhtml, m => $"<img style='width:{Application.Current.MainPage.Width -10}' src={urls[count]} />");
    count++
}
```

this will make all image the same image

Answer (score -1):

You must specify `1` in `regx.Replace()` to replace only the first occurence.

```
while (regx.IsMatch(newhtml) && count < urls.Count)
{
    newhtml = regx.Replace(newhtml, m => $"<img style='width: {Application.Current.MainPage.Width -10}' src={urls[count]} />", 1);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: What overload your `Replace` method matches?

Comment: [Replace(String, MatchEvaluator, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_System_Int32_).